# Protege reasoner not inferring subclasses of inverse of a property

Tags: ontology, protege, hermit

I am using protege5-5 and the reasoner HermiT 1.4 3.456.

I have a class `Animal` containing 2 subclasses `Animal1` and `Animal2`. I have a property `eats` and a property `isEatenBy` which is defined as the inverse of `eats`. When I add in the description of  `Animal1` that it's subclass of `eats some(Animal2)`, I expect the reasoner to add in the description of `Animal2` that it's a subclass of `isEatenBy Animal1` but it doesn't.

Any idea what should I do to make that happen or if what I am expecting is not supposed to happen anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 3 issues here.

(1) Stating `Animal1 SubClassOf eats some Animal2` merely states that there is a subset of individuals of the `Animal1` set that `eats` at least 1 individual that belongs to the set of `Animal2`. At most you can infer that some individuals of `Animal2` are eaten by `Animal1`. That is that `isEatenBy some Animal1 SubClassOf Animal2`. In (3) I will explain why you do not get this inference.

Most importantly it cannot infer that *all* individuals of `Animal2` are eaten by `Animal1`, which is what is needed to infer `Animal2 SubClassOf isEatenBy some Animal1`.

(2) Inverse roles make claims about individuals. Hence, when you have a statement about *specific individuals* like `eats(animal1, animal2)` where `animal1` and `animal2` are individuals, the reasoner will infer that `animal2 isEatenBy animal1`.

(3) A class like `isEatenBy some Animal1` is sometimes referred to as an anonymous class while classes like `Animal`, `Animal1` and `Animal2` are referred to as named classes. Because in general the number of inferences that can be made from a set of axioms is infinite, reasoners restrict their inferences to named classes.

As an example, for your `eats` property you can define the domain as `Animal1` and the range as `Animal2`. This means that whenever you have `eats(x, y)`, individuals `x` will be inferred to be of type `Animal1` and individual `y` will be inferred to be of type `Animal2`.

To now also get an inference that is the equivalent is `isEatenBy some Animal1 SubClassOf Animal2`, you need to introduce a new class, say `AnimalsThatAreEatenByAnimal1` that is equivalent to `isEatenBy some Animal1`. The reasoner will now infer that `AnimalsThatAreEatenByAnimal1` is a subclass of `Animal2`.

In general, to understand the inferences that a reasoner can make, it crucial to understand the semantics of the axioms you define. For this you can look at the [direct semantics](https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Direct_Semantics). For an introduction on the logic, see [An Introduction to Description Logics](http://an%20introduction%20to%20description%20logic).